# Как разместить ymaps.Polygon под ymaps.Layer?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Как разместить векторный объект под пользовательским растровым слоем в Яндекс.картах?
Полигон получатся всегда над растровым слоем.

```
var map;  
ymaps.ready(function(){
    var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([
            [
                [59.708794552,20.731157888],
                [59.708788452,20.731971641],
                [59.708618292,20.731984374],
                [59.708624453,20.731153111]
            ]
        ], {
            fillColor: '#00FF0088',
            fillOpacity: 100,
            zIndex: 100,
        });

    var MyLayer = function () {
        var layer = new ymaps.Layer('./%z/tile-%x-%y.png', {
                       zIndex:200
        });

        return layer;
    };

    ymaps.layer.storage.add('my_layers#layer1', MyLayer);

    var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [59.7074, 20.73184],
        zoom: 16,
        autoCentering: true,
        autoZooming: true,
        type:"yandex#hybrid",
        controls: ["rulerControl", "zoomControl"]
    },{
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 12
    });
    
    map.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);
    map.layers.add('my_layers#layer1');

});
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какую цель вы этим преследуете? Задача пользовательских геообъектов, коими являются и полигоны, обычно быть видимыми и интерактивными. Зачем вы хотите их убрать под слой?

Comment: Полигоны - динамически формируемые пользователем области карты(участки земли). На них хотелось расположить растровый слой с пользовательскими объектами(статический, например домами). В зависимости от статуса земли пользователь может менять цвет полигона(условно -занят/свободен).

Comment: Без рабочего примера сложно понять, что сейчас не работает. Вы вроде указали z-index в опциях. Также вариантом может быть использование кастомного пейна: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Layer.html#Layer__param-options.pane

Comment: Спасибо! Растровая пользовательская карта находится в ground пейне, векторы в areas. Помог перенос пользовательского слоя в areas пейн.